# How to remove newline and end character from input string in MIPS

Tags: mips, computer-science

I have this mips code:

```
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, promptInputRoman
    syscall

    jal _readString
    move $s0, $a0
```

and

```
_readString:
        li $v0, 8           # Syscall 8: Read string
        la $a0, buffer          # load byte space into address
        addi $a1, $zero, 20         # allot the byte space for string
        syscall
        jr   $ra
```

But the problem is that if I input something like `vii` as input, it has a newline after it and maybe other odd characters. How do I strip this character off. The issue is that when I output it later, the output looks like it has a newline and looks like this:

```
The integer value of vii
   is 7
```

Comment: By scanning the string for the newline character (0x0A) and replacing it with the value 0.

Comment: show me the way?